# gzipped asset pipeline for apache with phusion passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

So I am trying to gzip both of my application js and css, to load the page faster.

I have been following this [guide](https://coderwall.com/p/sx-8xa) to no avail.

Here is my httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.50/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so 
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.50 
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/wrappers/ruby 

RackEnv development

<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 127.0.0.1:80>
     ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/xxx/public
     <Directory /var/www/html/xxx/public>
         AllowOverride all
         Options -MultiViews
     </Directory>

    <Location /assets/>
        RewriteEngine on

        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} \b(x-)?gzip\b
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -s
        RewriteRule ^(.+) $1.gz [L]
    </Location>

    <FilesMatch \.css\.gz$>
        ForceType text/css
        Header set Content-Encoding gzip
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch \.js\.gz$>
        ForceType text/javascript
        Header set Content-Encoding gzip
    </FilesMatch>

</VirtualHost>
```

But it seems it has done nothing when checking the network timeline of the page when refreshing.

What am I missing here?